# Losing my TA-ship, need advice

Tags: phd, funding, united-states

I am a third year student in a U.S. university and for the past two years I was funded by dept. TA-ship.

The new semester is coming but I have not got the TA-ship. I contacted my advisor for help and he sent a note to a professor who is taking charge of all TA stuff and he also told me to hope for the best(My advisor and dept. secretary told me there would be a second round assignment).

Here is my question: How many chances do I have to get a TA offer? And I also want to ask my dept. why this thing is going to happen (because my GPA is over 3.5 and meet all requirements). I feel very frustrated and eager to know why. Would you please give me any advise?

Comment: How many chances do you have? It depends on the specific department, that we cannot know. Go ahead and ask. Also, inform your advisor how much you need that funding.

Answer (score 3):

Most graduate programs try to be more transparent and forthright about TA funding than seems to be the case for you. That is, at the outset there would be promises made about number of years of funding, conditional on reasonably good performance in coursework and teaching. Departments are very well aware that grad students will have difficulty surviving (much less paying tuition) without financial support, so do not usually cut support without considerable prior warning, explanation, explanation of terms for reinstatement, or explanation of economic conditions and prognosis for future funding. To do otherwise is irresponsible.

I do have to wonder whether you were paying attention to disclaimers about fragility of funding, though, too. For that matter, do you have a copy of the TA offer letter? It really should spell out what you can expect in terms of funding. For that matter, no one's advisor should be "the last to hear" that their student(s) didn't get TA funding renewed.

Of course, it might be that the central administration at your university "pulled the rug out from under" your department, and the budget changed abruptly and somewhat catastrophically. But, still, I'd think you would hear something about this, an explanation, rather than just a passive non-support situation arising.

Answer (score 2):

TA positions depend on availability of funding. A TA position is like a regular part-time job (albeit with low pay @). If the company falls short in budget, some employees can be laid off.

By being given a TA on your first day in grad school, there is no guarantee that you will have a TA for life. A TA can be taken away because of poor grades, low budget, or poor execution of TA responsibilities among others. The only issue I see here is that they must have warned you in advance about the possibility of your TA not being renewed for the third year. They also ought to have told you the reason for all this. All that said, you cannot build a case against them.

Answer (score 2):

TA positions by their very nature are most often intended to give teaching experience to as many graduate students as possible.  When, because of budgetary considerations, there aren't enough positions to cover three years of TAs, the third year students will go in favor of first-year students.  That being said, the number of classes will sometimes change if students are clamoring to get in, and sections can be added at the last minute.  My experience, anyway --